# Cuda C - Linker error - undefined reference

Tags: c, cuda, linker-errors

I am having a hard time compiling a simple cuda program consiting of only two files.

The main.c looks like this:

```
#include "my_cuda.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   dummy_gpu();
}
```

The cuda.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef MY_DUMMY
#define MY_DUMMY

void dummy_gpu();

#endif
```

And the my_cuda.cu file loos like this:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "my_cuda.h"

__global__ void dummy_gpu_kernel(){
   //do something
}

void dummy_gpu(){
   dummy_gpu_kernel<<<128,128>>>();
}
```

However if I compile I allways receive the following error:

```
gcc  -I/usr/local/cuda/5.0.35/include/ -c main.c
nvcc  -c my_cuda.cu
gcc  -L/usr/local_rwth/sw/cuda/5.0.35/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -o md.exe main.o my_cuda.o 
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `dummy_gpu'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My CUDA is rusty, but you shouldn't be able to call symbols compiled with the nvcc compiler. You need to setup a kernel and call the necessary launch functions, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The real question is: why not use nvcc for linking and let it do the hard work? Or use something like CMake?

Comment: CMake would fail as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a problem with symbol name mangling. `nvcc` uses the host C++ compiler to compile host code, and this implies that symbol [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) is applied to code emitted by the CUDA toolchain.

There are two solutions to this problem. The first is to define `dummy_gpu` using C linkage, so change your `my_cuda.cu` to something like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "my_cuda.h"
}

.....


extern "C"
void dummy_gpu(){
   dummy_gpu_kernel<<<128,128>>>();
}
```

Note that you will need to change your linkage command to this:

```
gcc -L/usr/local_rwth/sw/cuda/5.0.35/lib64 -o md.exe main.o my_cuda.o -lcuda -lcudart
```

because the CUDA shared libraries need to be specified *after* the object files that use them.

Your second alternative would be to use either `g++` or `nvcc` to do the linking, in which case the whole problem should disappear.

Comment: just using the g++ or nvcc for linking results in exactly the same error. What am I missing here?

Moreover, the first approach results in an different error:
gcc  -I/usr/local_rwth/sw/cuda/5.0.35/include/ -c main.c
nvcc  -c my_cuda.cu
my_cuda.cu(10): error: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "dummy_gpu"
my_cuda.h(4): here

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000061a8_00000000-6_my_cuda.cpp1.ii".

Comment: @user1829358: You will also need to modify how `my_cuda.h` in included into the .cu file. See the edit I made for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much talonmies, I was interested in how you discovered that nvcc used g++? I had my suspicions that some mangling was going on but I had no clue how to confirm!  Thanks again!

Comment: @Constantin: you can run nvcc with the --dryrun or --verbose options. This will print out the exact commands issued at each stage of compilation. From there you can see the g++/cl invocations where host code is compiled. You can also used elf/mach tools on Linux/OS X to dump the header tables of object files and see the presence of C++ name mangling, RTTI space, hooks into the standard library, etc.

Comment: I was on the right track then! I was examining the object files with `readelf -s` but I don't know what c++ name mangling and rtti space looked like. TIL.

Answer (score 8):

You have a C/C++ linkage problem.  nvcc is decorating things in a C++ fashion but your gcc compiler is handling things using C style linkage.  A simple way to fix it is to rename your main.c to main.cpp and then repeat your commands using g++ instead of gcc

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to compile the .c file with a C compiler and i can not remame it (this real project requires some features of the C compiler which are not yet supported by the C++ compiler)

Comment: Then I would suggest using the method that @talonmies has outlined, explicitly telling the c++ compiler to not mangle the function names that will be linked to the C side.  It seems to work for me.